# Wikipedia (WIL) to get named-entity translation

Tags: wikipedia

Does anyone know the way to get all the translation of the name of one entity stored in Wikipedia given its Wikipedia ID or English Title?

I haven't seen how to get them with the MEDIAWIKI API, but maybe someone found it in the past.

Comment: By "Wikipedia ID" you mean the pageid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this endpoint which return all the wikipedia translations for a given Wikipedia Title:

This is an example for London:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&redirects&format=json&titles=London&rawcontinue=true&lllimit=500

An other way is scrapping the HTML of the Wikipedia Page for the given entity, and getting from there all the translations looking into the `<a>` inside the `<li>` with `interlanguage-link interwiki-ace` as class

Comment: Just use a higher `lllimit` to get all interwikilinks ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&redirects&format=jsonfm&titles=London&lllimit=500))